# Best Channel for Mantra

Tags: puja, resource

I am looking for a respectable source for correct pronunciation of chants to the devatas, as many have said online that you must be careful with YouTube videos mispronouncing Mantras. Does anyone have a reputable source for correct mantra chanting?

Answer (score 1):

For Veda mantras, this is your best bet https://www.youtube.com/@TheGhanapati
It's not correct, but it's 100% authentic. It's as good as you will find anywhere else, if not better, and as accurate as you will find anywhere else (despite not being correct).

It's by a person with a variety of Shrotriyas who have learned the Veda in a mostly traditional way and the sound design is amazing.

For Taantrika/Aagamokta mantras, forget it, I haven't come across a single person even knowing that that अ 's correct pronunciation is like the A in fAther and not the U in fUn. Or, that you're supposed to pause after each word in a mantra. Or, that Anunaasikaas change depending on what word is next, eg:

**ओं** नमः शिवाय = **ओन्** नमः शिवाय and not **ओम्** नमः शिवाय

or that नमः isn't नमह or नमह् as 99% of people pronounce it.

And, these are seriously extremely basic things, that I can teach you in 30 minutes in detail with the whole theory and reasoning (that I'm not providing here) and application. Forget about anything like the correct pronunciation of ष, ज्ञ, र, ल (I can say with confidence that only a few thousand people in the world are pronouncing all of those correctly)  or the Anunasika changes before vowels and semi vowels etc etc.

Stay away from mantras, without a guru. Mantras can work without perfect pronunciation (half well), but without a guru, they don't work.